# Changing the numbering on an ordered list to reverse percentages

Tags: javascript, python, django, html-lists

I'm trying to give a percent matching score like 90% Match to each of my search results.

Is there any ways to write a function in python or to create some Javascript code that would automatically assign a random value from 100 to 0% (in reverse order) to every items inside of an ordered list (which are my search results) based on the default order of the list (1,2,3,4..).

The only problem is that I don't know the exact number of results that will be displayed since every queries can be different, and I'm using Elasticsearch as an index.

A quick example of the html:

```
<div>
{% if  page_obj.object_list %}
      <ol class="row top20">

        {% for result in page_obj.object_list %}

     <li class="list-item">
      <div class="showcase col-sm-6 col-md-4">
           <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">
              <h3>{{result.object.title}}</h3>
              <img src="{{ result.object.image }}" class="img-responsive">
           </a>
      </div>
     <li>

         {% endfor %}
      </ol>
</div>

{% else %}
        <p> Sorry, no result found </p>
{% endif %}
```

Now the final expected results should look to something like this:

```
- Title 1
  image...
  *100% Match*  <-- Random % Value based on the order -->

- Title 2
  image...
  *92% Match*

- Title 3
  image...
  *85% Match*

- Title 4
  image...
  *56% Match*
```

I'm literally open to any solutions at this point.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `a random value from 100% to 0% ( in reverse order )`? If it's a random value, there is no order. Do you mean to make something like a random value between 90-100 for the first result, 80-90 for the second, etc?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: And I just remembered that yes I can know in advance the number of items in the list since I can control the number of results to be paginated like so: `paginate_by = 20`, if it can helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple function with a loop that returns a random number between lower ranges every iteration until it reaches a point where it becomes zero:

```js
const data = [
    { title: "foo" },
    { title: "foo" },
    { title: "foo" },
    { title: "foo" },
    { title: "foo" },
    { title: "foo" },
    { title: "foo" },
    { title: "foo" },
    { title: "foo" },
    { title: "foo" },
    { title: "foo" },
]

let index = 0;
let results = [];
const randomSearchMatchPercentages = ( array ) => {
    for ( const element of array ) {
        // define a maximum and a minimum range
        const maximum = index <= 100 ? 100 - index : 0;
        const minimum = maximum > 0 ? maximum - 5 : 0;
 
        element.match = Math.round( Math.random() * ( maximum - minimum ) + minimum ) + "%";
        results.push( element );

        // decrease the maximum and minimum for the next iteration
        index += 5;
    }
console.log( results );
}

randomSearchMatchPercentages( data );
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Now, how can I implement this into my own javascript file and call this loop so that I can display it in the html example above?

Comment: That depends, I assume you're getting your data in an array format after your search. Maybe you could do an `onload= randomSearchMatchPercentages( data )`? Difficult to say to be honest, hope this gets you along the way though!

Comment: The only problem is that I can't define the data in a list like the example in `const data` above since all the data are coming from a postgresql database, so Is there a way to directly call the database or to connect this loop with my html above that is already connected to my database?

Comment: I have this Javascript code for my autocomplete, so I hope this can help to define the data name: `$(function () {
    'use strict';

    $('#q').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/autocomplete/",
    minChars: 2,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        console.log( suggestion.value + ', data :' + suggestion.data);
    }
});

});`

Comment: The data in my answer was just an example to get the code snippet running. 
I'm not sure how you're getting data from your database right now and I can't see the entire code, so I don't want to try to give you an answer that might be non-applicable or non-scaleable for whatever reason. If you can't figure it out, I suggest maybe creating another question on here so people with more knowledge on Django and HTML can help you out.